# ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular

I get this Error:

```
ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'ng-pristine': 'true'. Current value: 'false'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
    at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.mjs:8515:1)
    at bindingUpdated (core.mjs:12843:1)
    at checkStylingProperty (core.mjs:15448:1)
    at ɵɵclassProp (core.mjs:15356:1)
    at NgControlStatusGroup_HostBindings (ɵfac.js:1:1)
    at processHostBindingOpCodes (core.mjs:10087:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10372:1)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:11339:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:10350:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:11385:1)
```

I do not have *ngAfterViewInit* or *ngOnChanges* in mein code.

I followed the Debugging-description of [Angular](https://angular.io/errors/NG0100), but it is not the right solution for my case.

Comment: You are showing an error message with no code. It's literally impossible to tell what is wrong with your code if you don't show any code at all. You need to post any relevant code in your question if you want help with it.

Comment: Thank you Chris,
if I would know which part of the code would cause this error, I would share it. But I don't know, there is no hint in the error-message. I cannot share my hole app.
Maybe someone can first give a hint, where I can find the bug.

Comment: Since none of us know anything about you app it's impossible to say. You need to narrow down where the error is coming from at least.  See what you can comment out to make the error go away.  Just posting an error message with zero context isn't very useful, we know less about it than you do since you have all the code for the application we can't see.

Comment: Just ran into the same error, my setup was creating an input element that had both [formControl] and [ngModel] directives, the [ngModel] was a holdover from an earlier implementation and removing fixed this issue for me as the [formControl] handles it properly.